# Best strategy for locally storing remote data in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, caching, request, store

I have a Flutter app that has to request a considerable volume of JSON data from the network. This data has to be converted into a Map.

The remote data changes like every week or so, so I am looking for a way to "cache" or permanently store it in order not to have to request it every time the user opens the app.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hive [lib](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) to Save your data

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'main.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Person {
  Person({required this.name, required this.age, required this.friends});

  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  int age;

  @HiveField(2)
  List<String> friends;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name: $age';
  }
}

void main() async {
  var path = Directory.current.path;
  Hive
    ..init(path)
    ..registerAdapter(PersonAdapter());

  var box = await Hive.openBox('testBox');

  var person = Person(
    name: 'Dave',
    age: 22,
    friends: ['Linda', 'Marc', 'Anne'],
  );

  await box.put('dave', person);

  print(box.get('dave')); // Dave: 22
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something quick, you can store that data in a file ([source](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)) using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

Create a reference to the file location:

```
Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return File('$path/counter.txt');
}
```

Write data:

```
Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  return file.writeAsString('$counter');
}
```

Read data:

```
Future<int> readCounter() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;
    final contents = await file.readAsString();
    return int.parse(contents);
  } catch (e) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

If you want to know all the options you have I suggest you read this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro